# FlatBuffer: How do I dynamically add fields to a table?

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization, flatbuffers

I have a table in my schema that is empty (as shown below).

```
table ClusterValue 
{
}
```

Since I do not know the number of member elements in the cluster in advance, I'd like to programatically add fields (C++). I came across some methods like AddOffset, AddElement, AddStruct. But I am not still sure of the exact way to add that.

To elaborate, let say if the input to my program is a cluster with two members - a string and a numeric. I'd like to programatically add two fields (string and numeric) to the cluster table and serialize it.

Comment: Are you talking about a C++ struct, or are you talking about a database? And if so, what kind of database?

Comment: I'm talking about the table in a schema file that is needed for flatbuffers. So, a schema file with the above table and that as the root table. let say I run flatc.exe to generate a C++ header file. Now, in the application, I need to serialize this cluster table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. FlatBuffers is a statically typed system, and all possible fields have to be known in advance, with C++ code generated for their construction and access. While you can dynamically decide which fields to add to a table (by calling `add_field_name()` based on some condition), it has to be one of the fields in the schema.

If that is not dynamic enough for you, I'd recommend FlexBuffers (https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flexbuffers.html) which gives you the efficiency of FlatBuffers with the dynamic nature of JSON. Here you can start a vector or a map, and add any values or fields to them at runtime, with no limitations.